# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation EF core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 6 for these 3 tables:

[image: Database Tables]

This here are the 2 model classes for these tables:

```
public partial class QualityControlSchema : MainBaseEntity
{
    public QualityControlSchema()
    {
        Levels = new HashSet<Level>();
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public Guid? SiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Level> Levels { get; set; }
}

public partial class Level : MainBaseEntity
{
    public Level()
    {
        QualityControlSchemas = new HashSet<QualityControlSchema>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<QualityControlSchema> QualityControlSchemas { get; set; }
}
```

And the `DbContext` is like this:

```
public virtual DbSet<QualityControlSchema> QualityControlSchemas { get; set; } = null!;
public virtual DbSet<Level> Levels { get; set; } = null!;

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Level>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Level");

    
                entity.HasMany(d => d.QualityControlSchemas)
                  .WithMany(p => p.Levels)
                  .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                      "QualityControlSchemaLevels",
                      l => l.HasOne<QualityControlSchema>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("QualityControlSchemaId").HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.QualityControlSchemaLevels_dbo.QualityControlSchema_QualityControlSchemaId"),
                      r => r.HasOne<Level>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("LevelId").HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.QualityControlSchemaLevels_dbo.Level_LevelId"),
                      j =>
                      {
                          j.HasKey("QualityControlSchemaId", "LevelId").HasName("PK_dbo.QualityControlSchemaLevels");

                          j.ToTable("QualityControlSchemaLevels");
                          j.HasIndex(new[] { "LevelId" }, "IX_LevelId");
                          j.HasIndex(new[] { "QualityControlSchemaId" }, "IX_QualityControlSchemaId");
                      });

            modelBuilder.Entity<QualityControlSchema>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("QualityControlSchema");                  
    
                entity.HasMany(d => d.Levels)
                    .WithMany(p => p.QualityControlSchemas)
                    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                        "QualityControlSchemaLevels",
                        l => l.HasOne<Level>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("LevelId").HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.QualityControlSchemaLevels_dbo.Level_LevelId"),
                        r => r.HasOne<QualityControlSchema>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("QualityControlSchemaId").HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.QualityControlSchemaLevels_dbo.QualityControlSchema_QualityControlSchemaId"),
                        j =>
                        {
                            j.HasKey("QualityControlSchemaId", "LevelId").HasName("PK_dbo.QualityControlSchemaLevels");                                j.ToTable("QualityControlSchemaLevels");
                            j.HasIndex(new[] { "LevelId" }, "IX_LevelId");

                            j.HasIndex(new[] { "QualityControlSchemaId" }, "IX_QualityControlSchemaId");
                        });
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<QualityControlSchema>().Ignore(q => q.SiteId);}
```

but I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'QualityControlSchema.Site' of type 'Level'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'

I've tried to mark this property as `[NotMapped]` and change the `OnModelCreating` with no use, also I've tried to remove this property and the error still appear.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6imZC.jpg)

Very important note: `Site` class inherits from `Level` class.

This is the `Site.cs` file:

```
[NotMapped]
public class Site : Level
{
}
```

Comment: When do you get the error? It also already looks as if you commented out a lot of stuff. That's confusing. Please keep situations consistent and separated.

Comment: Yes, you should show the code that throws the exception, not mixed with efforts to fix it. Also, it would help to reduce it to the essentials. You can remove 90% of properties and and mapping code.

Comment: @JHBonarius I've simplified the Code

Comment: @GertArnold I've simplified the Code

Comment: you didn't answer my question: **_when did you get the error?_** If you delete something and you still get an error about it, something's wrong. did you get a build error and are running the old assemblies? Or you you have Site defined elsewhere?

Comment: @JHBonarius the error occurs on runtime in 

`public DkhCleaningSystemDevContext(DbContextOptions<DkhCleaningSystemDevContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        } `
I've attached screenshot of the error

Comment: @JHBonarius and I've removed "Site" from the whole application and I couldn't find where the issue is